# App not respond when trying to connect to a closed connection via HTTPUrlConnection

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I'm using HTTPUrlConnection in connecting to my database (mysql)

How can I know without interruption on the app if there's no connection as seen on the video:

[Video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=0qtidMRWgco&feature=youtu.be)

My app not respond because I shut down mysql. But what I want to do is it will just display progressbar until reaching the connection timeout but it should not be interrupted. Just want to do this because if the server is not  working it should display the error but it shouldn't hang.

```
class VerifyEmailTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    // use doInBackground() to make network calls, the returned value is
    // sent to onPostExecute()
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... data) {
        String accountURL =  DataClass.localAddress + "android_php/account.php";
        try {
            url = new URL(accountURL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.connect();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            displaySnackBar("Failed to connect to the server. Please check your network connection.").show();
            return false;
        }

  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Another thing is, why is it the responseCode of the connection is still 200 even on my xampp control panel, mysql is off.

Comment: at where you're checking for status/responseCode ?

Comment: In doInBackground()  method you can not perform UI Interaction .
so  remove the  displaySnackBar display from doInBackground()

If you use  UI Interaction put into onPreExecute() method

Comment: im sorry i removed it right after connection.connect(). my only problem is the app not responds until reaching connection timeout. (as seen on the video).. is there other way to check if the connection is refused.

Comment: i just want to remove that "not responding" part right after pressing the button